# python - class not returning the expected result. I am using function and a class

Tags: python, object-oriented, functional-programming

I am trying to pass 2 values from a function to the class and get a result from the class. For example, if I send value "dog" I should get the result as "dog runs" as a returned result. Need help with the code.

```
class secrets:
    def __init__(self,which,why):
        self.which=which
        self.why=why

    def mixed(self,which, why):
        which=["dog", "cat", "bird", "crow"]
        why=["runs","jumps", "flies", "talks"]
        if ("dog" in which):
            message=("dog"+ " " +why[0])
            print(message)
            return(message)
        else:
            print("dog not found")
            return(message)

asecret=secrets("which","why")
amessage=asecret.mixed("dog","dontknow")
```

Comment: Welcome to code review where we review working code to provide suggestions on how that code can be improved. Code that is not working as expected is off-topic for this site. If you follow the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help you might be able to get help on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1):

This code does in fact print the expected result of `dog runs`, so I'm going to go ahead and give it a quick review.

First: your `mixed` method does not use the `self` parameter, so it could be a `@staticmethod`.  Figuring out which of your object's methods actually depend on the object state makes it easier to figure out which methods might affect each other.

Since after that change your class consists only of a single static method, the object itself is superfluous; it should just be a function:

```
def mixed(which, why):
    which=["dog", "cat", "bird", "crow"]
    why=["runs","jumps", "flies", "talks"]
    if ("dog" in which):
        message=("dog"+ " " +why[0])
        print(message)
        return(message)
    else:
        print("dog not found")
        return(message)
```

Now, looking closer at this function: the `which` and `why` parameters are discarded (you assign new values to those names before reading the caller's passed-in values), so we could more simply write this function with no parameters at all and it would still produce the same result:

```
def mixed():
    which=["dog", "cat", "bird", "crow"]
    why=["runs","jumps", "flies", "talks"]
    if ("dog" in which):
        message=("dog"+ " " +why[0])
        print(message)
        return(message)
    else:
        print("dog not found")
        return(message)
```

Now it's easy to see how we can simplify this code further:

1. Since we define `which` statically as a list that contains `"dog"`, the `if`/`else` is just dead code.  Always eliminate dead code!
2. Having removed that `if` check, `which` itself becomes superfluous, since that was the only thing we used it for.

Now our simplified code is:

```
def mixed():
    why=["runs","jumps", "flies", "talks"]
    message=("dog"+ " " +why[0])
    print(message)
    return(message)
```

We only ever use the first element of `why` (i.e. we're not doing something like `random.choice(why)` which would give us a random element, we're just always asking for the `[0]`th element), so the rest of that list is also dead code, and we can delete it with no ill effect:

```
def mixed():
    why=["runs"]
    message=("dog"+ " " +why[0])
    print(message)
    return(message)
```

And since `why[0]` is just always `"runs"` we can in fact just generate `message` as a single static string and it will produce the same result without unnecessary obfuscation:

```
def mixed():
    message = "dog runs"
    print(message)
    return(message)
```

This function does the same exact thing as the method in your original class, but is only 3 lines of implementation and is much easier to read and maintain.  I'd suggest adding type annotations and a docstring as well, so that future developers will know exactly what the function does without even having to read those 3 lines:

```
def mixed() -> str:
    """Prints and returns the message 'dog runs'."""
    message = "dog runs"
    print(message)
    return(message)
```